# MKT Cloud Landing Page grab current user's email

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

I have browsed through SFDC documentation and am not seeing anything based around this functionality. Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

@LukasLunow actually, I'm looking for the user logged into marketing cloud, the page will be sort of an admin console

Comment: @LukasLunow actually, I'm looking for the user logged into marketing cloud, the page will be sort of an admin console.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Microsites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsites.htm&type=5) enabled in Classic Content, selecting the [System Authenticated Redirection](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_microsite_landing_page.htm&type=5) option in the Security property setting will allow you to use the [AuthenticatedEmployeeNotificationAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/authenticatedemployeenotificationaddress.htm) function.

Note: this won't work with CloudPages

```
%%[
var @userEmail
set @userEmail = AuthenticatedEmployeeNotificationAddress()

output(v(@userEmail))
]%%
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that classic content will be retired soon (early 2020)

Comment: @LukasLunow that's a good reminder. Also note that unlike classic emails, classic Landing Pages and Microsites will continue to be supported after that retirement date: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_classic_landing_pages_and_microsites.htm&type=5

Comment: @MarkG microsites and landing pages in Cloud Pages a very different from the one in Classic Content

Comment: @SamuelDare the answer I provided is for classic content (I already mentioned that it won't work with CloudPages).